redux-toolkit - state updated but still getting initial state value when using it
I have been trying to solve the issue below for quite some time but haven't been able to figure out what is wrong.
I am dispatching an action from my component, and the state is getting updated, as confirmed by logging it in the action. However, when I try to access the value of the state immediately after dispatching the action, it still shows the initial state value.
Please have a look at the below code.
entitySlice.js
export const entitySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'entity',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setEntity: (state, action) => {
            state = action.payload;
            console.log(state.entityAttributes);
        },
    },
});

export const { setEntity } = entitySlice.actions;
export default entitySlice.reducer;

Editor.jsx
const EntityEditor = () => {
   const effectRan = useRef(false);
   const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const entityData1 = useSelector((state) => state.entity);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (!effectRan.current) {
         effectRan.current = true;
         getEntityData();
      }
   });

   const getEntityData = () => {
      entityOperations.getEntity(searchParams.get("PK_Entity")).then(function (response) {
         dispatch(setEntity(response));
         console.log(entityData1);
      },
         function (error) {
            console.log(error);
         }
      );
   };
}

I am getting the correct response from the API, and the state value is changing as expected when I check it using console.log(state.entityAttributes);. However, when I check the data using console.log(entityData1);, I still see the initial state value, not the updated one. Any pointers on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Probably similar problem to this

@James It would have been same if I was using useState, but I am using redux-toolkit to maintain state here.

Sometimes, when getting values from the Redux store, the initial value is always shown because the function is made static by React. To always get the current value, you can use 'store.getState()'.

@LazyJ can you give an example of the usage? Sample code based on my example would be nice.

entityData1 is declared as a const, mostly to draw you to the conclusion that it can’t change ( until the useSelector runs again next render )

There is one problem and one misunderstanding in your code.
The main issue is that you are reassigning to the state variable in your reducer. This is something that cannot be detected by Redux Toolkit (it can only detect mutations to the state variable), you need instead to return the new state (as documented here and here).
// state = action.payload; // Incorrect
return action.payload; // Correct

The misunderstanding is that the following piece of code will log the new data:
dispatch(setEntity(response));
console.log(entityData1);

This is not possible. In Javascript, function calls (like the call to dispatch) cannot reassign local variables of the calling function, so entityData1 cannot possibly be different just after the dispatch. What will happen, however, is that React will schedule a rerender of the component, which means that your component will be called one more time, this time with the new data. So you should put your console.log(entityData1) directly in the body of the component if you want to see it change.

As I said in my comment the issue is related to the fact that JavaScript captures the values in the Redux store during the last render which means that it doesn't get the updated values. I was also wrong in that I missed that you don't return the new state or payload entity which means that it isn't being set. Here is a fix I made, note that I made it in TypeScript cause it makes more sense, lowkey biased, and I used some mock data since I didn't want to spin up some random backend for it.
App.tsx, which is your Editor.jsx
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getMockData } from './MockData';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setEntity } from './Redux/EntitySlice';
import store from './Redux/store';

const App = () => {
    const effectRan = useRef(false);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!effectRan.current) {
            effectRan.current = true;
            getEntityData();
        }
    });

    const getEntityData = () => {
        getMockData().then(
            function (response) {
                dispatch(setEntity(response));
                console.log(store.getState().entity);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    };

    return <div></div>;
};

export default App;

EntitySlice.ts, which is your entitySlice.js
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { card } from '../MockData';

const initialState: card[] = [];

export const entitySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'entity',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setEntity: (_, action: PayloadAction<card[]>) => {
            return action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setEntity } = entitySlice.actions;
export default entitySlice.reducer;

With this setup it worked for me. Hope it helps, otherwise just make a comment and I take another look and edit my answer :-)

React does not "make functions static" (what does that even mean?).

True it does not "make them static", it captures the values during the last render, which can result in outdated values if the state or props have changed since then. This behavior is similar to how a static function would behave, always returning the same value regardless of changes in state or props. Of course I might be wrong, if you know that it actually works in some other way feel free to tell me.

This is not specific to React or static methods, this is how all functions behave in Javascript. In Javascript it is not possible to reassign a local variable from an outside function, for instance entityData1 is a local variable in the EntityEditor function, so a call to dispatch cannot possibly change its value.

Yep true it's JavaScript and not React specific
